# What does it mean if Gauss-Newton converges in one iteration with a particular choice of initialisation?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

I have a nonlinear least squares optimisation problem. With a particular choice of initialisation, it appears that the Gauss-Newton method always converges in one iteration for my problem. With a random initialisation, Gauss-Newton appears to still converge to the same solution but takes more iterations.

What does this say about my residual function?

Comment: If you start with a point so close to the result, the next iteration will be so close such that you won't notice the change or that point is the true root.

Comment: Ok, but for my problem the initialisation that converges in one iteration is not close to the solution obtained after one iteration.

Comment: There are cases when the Newton's method won't work. For example, you can form the iterative formula in different ways, not all may converge. Also, when you choose a point where $f'(x) =0$ (an inflection point) the iterations may diverge and not converge back to the root. Also, when you perform division by near-zero values, the method may diverge. See more here: https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=bCl_AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA175&dq=newton+diverge+numerical&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB3-HQ2s_iAhXLDuwKHY-JBqwQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=newton%20diverge%20numerical&f=false